Movenet's Singlepose Lighting model in Android : "Unsupported image format: 1" Error
I'm currently building a Pose Estimation Android App which detects keypoints of human body joints. I'm using Movenet's Singlepose Lighting model and was trying to integrate into Android Application.
Here's my issue.
Link to the Model
The model seems to not accept the image and always returning  E  Unsupported image format: 1 into the Logcat.
Snippet of my code:
CameraActivity (startCamera function)
private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            val resolutionSelector = ResolutionSelector.Builder()
                .setAspectRatioStrategy(AspectRatioStrategy.RATIO_16_9_FALLBACK_AUTO_STRATEGY)
                .build()
            val imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setResolutionSelector(resolutionSelector)
                .setTargetRotation(binding.viewFinder.display.rotation)
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .setOutputImageFormat(ImageAnalysis.OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_RGBA_8888)
                .build()
            imageAnalyzer.setAnalyzer(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()) { image ->
                poseEstimationHelper.detectPose(image)
            }

            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            val preview = Preview.Builder().build().also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(binding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
            }
            try {
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this,
                    cameraSelector,
                    preview,
                    imageAnalyzer
                )
            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@CameraActivity,
                    "Failed to start the camera.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                Log.e(TAG, "startCamera: ${exc.message}")
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

PoseEstimationHelper
class PoseEstimationHelper(
    val context: Context,
    val detectorListener: DetectorListener?,
    private val onError: (String) -> Unit,
) {
    private var interpreter: Interpreter? = null
    private var initializationTask: Task<Void>? = null

    init {
        initializationTask = TfLiteGpu.isGpuDelegateAvailable(context).onSuccessTask { gpuAvailable ->
            val optionsBuilder = TfLiteInitializationOptions.builder()
            if (gpuAvailable) {
                optionsBuilder.setEnableGpuDelegateSupport(true)
            }
            TfLiteVision.initialize(context, optionsBuilder.build())
        }.addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.d(TAG, "TfLiteVision initialized successfully")
            downloadModel()
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            val errorMsg = context.getString(R.string.tflitevision_is_not_initialized_yet)
            detectorListener?.onError(errorMsg)
            onError(errorMsg)
            Log.e(TAG, "TfLiteVision initialization failed", it)
        }
    }

    @Synchronized
    private fun downloadModel() {
        val conditions = CustomModelDownloadConditions.Builder()
            .requireWifi()
            .build()
        FirebaseModelDownloader.getInstance()
            .getModel("singlepose-movenet-lightning", DownloadType.LOCAL_MODEL, conditions)
            .addOnSuccessListener { model: CustomModel ->
                try {
                    val modelFile = model.file
                    if (modelFile != null) {
                        setupModel(modelFile)
                    } else {
                        throw IOException("Model file is null")
                    }
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    val errorMsg = e.message.toString()
                    detectorListener?.onError(errorMsg)
                    onError(errorMsg)
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e: Exception? ->
                val errorMsg = context.getString(R.string.firebaseml_model_download_failed)
                detectorListener?.onError(errorMsg)
                onError(errorMsg)
                Log.e(TAG, "Model download failed", e)
            }
    }

    private fun setupModel(modelFile: File) {
        val options = Interpreter.Options()
        if (CompatibilityList().isDelegateSupportedOnThisDevice) {
            options.addDelegate(org.tensorflow.lite.gpu.GpuDelegate())
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            options.useNNAPI = true
        } else {
            options.setNumThreads(4)
        }

        try {
            interpreter = Interpreter(modelFile, options)
            Log.d(TAG, "Pose estimation model set up successfully")
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            val errorMsg = context.getString(R.string.image_classifier_failed)
            detectorListener?.onError(errorMsg)
            onError(errorMsg)
            Log.e(TAG, "Pose estimation model setup failed", e)
        }
    }

    fun detectPose(image: ImageProxy) {
        initializationTask?.addOnSuccessListener {
            if (!TfLiteVision.isInitialized()) {
                val errorMessage = context.getString(R.string.tflitevision_is_not_initialized_yet)
                Log.e(TAG, errorMessage)
                detectorListener?.onError(errorMessage)
                onError(errorMessage)
                return@addOnSuccessListener
            }

            if (interpreter == null) {
                val errorMsg = "Pose estimation model is not set up yet"
                detectorListener?.onError(errorMsg)
                onError(errorMsg)
                return@addOnSuccessListener
            }

            try {
                val bitmap = toBitmap(image)
                val resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 192, 192, true)

                val imageProcessor = ImageProcessor.Builder()
                    .add(ResizeOp(192, 192, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR))
                    .add(Rot90Op(-image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees / 90))
                    .add(NormalizeOp(0f, 1f))
                    .build()

                val tensorImage = imageProcessor.process(TensorImage.fromBitmap(resizedBitmap))
                val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 192, 192, 3), DataType.FLOAT32)
                inputFeature0.loadBuffer(tensorImage.buffer)

                val outputBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 1, 17, 3), DataType.FLOAT32)

                var inferenceTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
                interpreter?.run(inputFeature0.buffer, outputBuffer.buffer.rewind())
                inferenceTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - inferenceTime

                val keypoints = extractKeypoints(outputBuffer)
                detectorListener?.onResults(keypoints, inferenceTime)
            } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                val errorMessage = e.message ?: "Unknown error"
                Log.e(TAG, errorMessage)
                detectorListener?.onError(errorMessage)
                onError(errorMessage)
            } finally {
                image.close()
            }
        }?.addOnFailureListener {
            val errorMessage = context.getString(R.string.tflitevision_is_not_initialized_yet)
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage)
            detectorListener?.onError(errorMessage)
            onError(errorMessage)
        }
    }

    private fun toBitmap(image: ImageProxy): Bitmap {
        Log.d(TAG, "Image format: ${image.format}")
        return when (image.format) {
            ImageFormat.YUV_420_888 -> {
                val yBuffer = image.planes[0].buffer
                val uBuffer = image.planes[1].buffer
                val vBuffer = image.planes[2].buffer

                val ySize = yBuffer.remaining()
                val uSize = uBuffer.remaining()
                val vSize = vBuffer.remaining()

                val nv21 = ByteArray(ySize + uSize + vSize)

                yBuffer.get(nv21, 0, ySize)
                vBuffer.get(nv21, ySize, vSize)
                uBuffer.get(nv21, ySize + vSize, uSize)

                val yuvImage = YuvImage(nv21, ImageFormat.NV21, image.width, image.height, null)
                val out = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                yuvImage.compressToJpeg(Rect(0, 0, image.width, image.height), 100, out)
                val yuvByteArray = out.toByteArray()
                BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(yuvByteArray, 0, yuvByteArray.size)
            }
            ImageFormat.JPEG -> {
                val buffer = image.planes[0].buffer
                Log.d(TAG, "JPEG buffer size: ${buffer.remaining()}")
                val bytes = ByteArray(buffer.remaining())
                buffer.get(bytes)
                BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
            }
            ImageFormat.RGB_565 -> {
                val buffer = image.planes[0].buffer
                val bytes = ByteArray(buffer.remaining())
                buffer.get(bytes)
                BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
            }
            else -> {
                val errorMsg = "Unsupported image format: ${image.format}"
                Log.e(TAG, errorMsg)
                throw IllegalArgumentException(errorMsg)
            }
        }
    }


    private fun extractKeypoints(outputBuffer: TensorBuffer): List<Keypoint> {
        val keypoints = mutableListOf<Keypoint>()
        val scores = outputBuffer.floatArray

        // Assume that each keypoint has 3 values: x, y, and score
        for (i in scores.indices step 3) {
            val x = scores[i]
            val y = scores[i + 1]
            val score = scores[i + 2]
            keypoints.add(Keypoint(x, y, score))
        }
        return keypoints
    }

    interface DetectorListener {
        fun onError(error: String)
        fun onResults(
            keypoints: List<Keypoint>?,
            inferenceTime: Long
        )
    }

    data class Keypoint(val x: Float, val y: Float, val score: Float)

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "PoseEstimationHelper"
    }
}

I have tried to change the toBitmap function, adding numerous different ImageFormat scenario. Still returns the same error.
